# jQuery click event target is the inner est HTML element

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, onclick, jquery-events, event-propagation

I handle the click event of a nested element

element1->
 element2->
  element3

```
$(document).on("click",  function(e){})
$(document).on("click", "#element3", function(e){})
```

However on IE10 the event target is always element3 and in a result of it the element's click event is fired before document's click event.

If I test this on other browsers including IE11 the event target is always the outerest (element1)

Can I change the IE10 default behavior? I tried to put prevent propagation but it doesn't help

```
$(document).on("click", "#element3", function(e){ e.stopPropagation(()});
```

Comment: Innerest? Outerest? Seriously?

Comment: If ideally you want the event target to be the document, why don't you just reference the document in your callback instead of the event target?